# Control Not move in drag and drop

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drag-and-drop

In my Application i want to move the control one side another side. That control inside the tablelayoutpanel. I would like to drag the control which is inside the panel and the panel is inside the table layout panel so first i remove the control form panel and add the control in form after that i drag the button control its make the issue not clearly dragging. (that means drag fast its not working properly). My Code is

```
Private Sub HandleDraggableControlMouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseDown
    Dim target As Control = TryCast(sender, Control)
    Dim xWidth, xHeight As Integer

    If (Not target Is Nothing) Then

        xWidth = sender.Width
        xHeight = sender.Height
        sender.Parent.Controls.Remove(sender)
        sender.Dock = DockStyle.None

        sender.Width = xWidth
        sender.Height = xHeight
        Me.Controls.Add(sender)

        Dim pt As Point = Me.PointToClient(target.PointToScreen(Point.Empty))
        target.Location = pt
        target.Parent = Me
        target.BringToFront()
        Me.isMouseDown = True
        Me.cachedControlPos = pt
        Me.cachedMousePos = Control.MousePosition

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub HandleDraggableControlMouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseMove
    If (Me.isMouseDown) Then
        Dim target As Control = TryCast(sender, Control)
        If (Not target Is Nothing) Then
            Dim x As Integer = (Me.cachedControlPos.X + (Control.MousePosition.X - Me.cachedMousePos.X))
            Dim y As Integer = (Me.cachedControlPos.Y + (Control.MousePosition.Y - Me.cachedMousePos.Y))
            target.Location = New Point(x, y)

            'c2 = (c1 + (m2 - m1))

        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub HandleDraggableControlMouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseUp
    Me.cachedControlPos = Point.Empty
    Me.cachedMousePos = Point.Empty
    Me.isMouseDown = False
End Sub
```

My problem is if drag the control fast the control not moved cursor only moved why?. What am doing wrong in my coding?. How is solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the difference between the current mouse position **`m2`** and the cached mouse position **`m1`**  to a *cached control position* **`c1`** to give you the current control position **`c2`**.

```
c2 = (c1 + (m2 - m1))
```

Something like this:

```
sender.Location = New Point(
    (cachedControlLocation.X + (e.X - startX)), 
    (cachedControlLocation.Y + (e.Y - startY))
)
```

Here's a sample form to show you how it works:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.ClientSize = New Size(800, 600)
        Me.panel1 = New Panel() With {.Bounds = New Rectangle(10, 10, 300, 300), .BackColor = Color.Red}
        Me.panel2 = New Panel() With {.Bounds = New Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 200), .BackColor = Color.Green}
        Me.panel3 = New Panel() With {.Bounds = New Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100), .BackColor = Color.Blue}
        Me.panel2.Controls.Add(Me.panel3)
        Me.panel1.Controls.Add(Me.panel2)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.panel1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleDraggableControlMouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles panel1.MouseDown, panel2.MouseDown, panel3.MouseDown
        Dim target As Control = TryCast(sender, Control)
        If (Not target Is Nothing) Then
            Dim pt As Point = Me.PointToClient(target.PointToScreen(Point.Empty))
            target.Parent = Me
            target.BringToFront()
            target.Location = pt
            Me.isMouseDown = True
            Me.cachedControlPos = pt
            Me.cachedMousePos = Control.MousePosition
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleDraggableControlMouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles panel1.MouseMove, panel2.MouseMove, panel3.MouseMove
        If (Me.isMouseDown) Then
            Dim target As Control = TryCast(sender, Control)
            If (Not target Is Nothing) Then
                Dim x As Integer = (Me.cachedControlPos.X + (Control.MousePosition.X - Me.cachedMousePos.X))
                Dim y As Integer = (Me.cachedControlPos.Y + (Control.MousePosition.Y - Me.cachedMousePos.Y))
                target.Location = New Point(x, y)

                'c2 = (c1 + (m2 - m1))

            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleDraggableControlMouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles panel1.MouseUp, panel2.MouseUp, panel3.MouseUp
        Me.cachedControlPos = Point.Empty
        Me.cachedMousePos = Point.Empty
        Me.isMouseDown = False
    End Sub

    Private cachedMousePos As Point
    Private cachedControlPos As Point
    Private isMouseDown As Boolean

    Private WithEvents panel1 As Panel
    Private WithEvents panel2 As Panel
    Private WithEvents panel3 As Panel

End Class
```

**Update 1**

It's important that you set the new location *after* you've changed the parent and moved it to the front.

```
target.Parent = Me
target.BringToFront()
target.Location = pt '<---
```

**Update 2**

So I've narrowed it down to what's causing this issue, and it turns out to be the `Selectable` [control style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can verify this by subclassing the button class and remove the style in the constructor.

```
Public Class UIButton
    Inherits Button

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, False)
    End Sub

End Class
```

So how can we fix this? Well, AFAIK there's no easy solution. It's to be expected that a selectable control will process the mouse messages in a different way than those who can't. The only way I can think of (and it might be a dirty one) is to subclass the control(s) and intercept the mouse messages. The following code is not a final solution, so use it with caution.

```
Public Class UIButton
    Inherits Button

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        Select Case m.Msg
            Case WM.LBUTTONDOWN
                Dim dw As New DWORD With {.value = m.LParam}
                Dim vk As Integer = m.WParam.ToInt32()
                MyBase.OnMouseDown(New MouseEventArgs(Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left, 0, dw.loword, dw.hiword, 0))
                Debug.WriteLine("X={0}, Y={1}", dw.loword, dw.hiword)
                Exit Select
            Case WM.MOVE
                Dim dw As New DWORD With {.value = m.LParam}
                Dim vk As Integer = m.WParam.ToInt32()
                If (vk = Keys.LButton) Then
                    MyBase.OnMouseMove(New MouseEventArgs(Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left, 0, dw.loword, dw.hiword, 0))
                    Debug.WriteLine("X={0}, Y={1}", dw.loword, dw.hiword)
                End If
                Exit Select
            Case WM.LBUTTONUP
                Dim dw As New DWORD With {.value = m.LParam}
                Dim vk As Integer = m.WParam.ToInt32()
                MyBase.OnMouseUp(New MouseEventArgs(Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left, 0, dw.loword, dw.hiword, 0))
                Debug.WriteLine("X={0}, Y={1}", dw.loword, dw.hiword)
                Exit Select
        End Select
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

    Private Enum WM As Integer
        MOVE = &H200
        LBUTTONDOWN = &H201
        LBUTTONUP = &H202
    End Enum

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)> _
    Private Structure DWORD
        <FieldOffset(0)> Public value As Integer
        <FieldOffset(0)> Public loword As Short
        <FieldOffset(2)> Public hiword As Short
    End Structure

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply. i would like to drag the control which is inside the panel and the panel is inside the table layout panel so first i remove the control form panel and add the control in form after that i drag the button control its make the issue not clearly dragging. (that means drag fast its not working properly)

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample form highlighting the issue? I cannot reproduce the inconveniences with the current code. Btw, your naming convention is a bit strange. For instance, do you really expect the sender to be a `KryptonGroupPanel` if the method is named `Button_MouseDown`? Also, your code are full of late bindings. You should turn option strict `on`.

Comment: Thanks. But that also i move the cursor fast the cursor leave the control

Comment: check like this. add table layout panel dock fill in form. add panel in in table layout panel dock fill after that add button in side the panel now check it. move the cursor fast the cursor leave the control